# Videos Delivery service for Learning magement System(LMS)

Tags: wordpress, video, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming

I am working on Wordpress based LMS. For courses videos, I need video delivery Service that  full fill following services

1. Course Videos  uploaded  by instructors directly upload to  service provider server  and streamed from service provider server
2. Course Enrolled students not able to download the videos,  only watch them online.

I google  for this, then two option AMAZON S3 and cloudfront came across me. But I am little bit  confuse what is right choice for my requirements ?  Any other videos  delivery service that include free tier also welcome.